# JavaScript validation not triggering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a JS function to execute when a submit button is pressed.

```
<td colspan="2" align="center"><button
             onclick="return myFunction()">test</button></td>
```

The above line work fine. But when I submit the form using the chrome browser's console window

```
document.getElementById("use").value=99;
        document.forms[0].submit();
```

The myFunction does not get executed. How can I get it executed if I am submitting the form from the console.Thanks.

Comment: well you are submitting the form, not clicking the button. So maybe you should be calling the function onsubmit of the form, not the button click

Comment: Your button is not submitting a form. Its calling a function. To have a button submit a form us an input with type `submit`. Or you can just call the function from the console instead like the button is currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two approaches here.

1. Submit the form on the `onsubmit` event for the form

```js
var submitFunction = function() {
    alert("onsubmit event");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitFunction()">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <button type="submit">test</button>       
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

2. Call the `submit()` from an `onclick` method

```js
var myFunction = function() {
    alert("onclick event");
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>       
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function does not fire because you’re not clicking the button.  Bind to the form’s onsubmit event instead.